# Accessing Scope from Directive Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the right way to access scope variables from a controller defined in a directive?

Example, I want to have the click event call a function on the parent directive's controller.  In the parent directive, I want the controller to have access to the "constants", FOO_VIEW, BAR_VIEW, BAM_VIEW

Would it make more sense to put those constants in the top level controller, in this case SearchCtrl (not shown)?

Directives:

```
.directive('usersAndApps', function() {
        return {
            restrict:'EA',
            scope: true,
            controller: function() {
                this.toggleView = function(viewName){
                    console.log('show view ' + viewName);
                }
            },
            link:function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.FOO_VIEW = 'fooView';
                scope.BAR_VIEW = 'barView';
                scope.BAM_VIEW = 'bamView';
            }
        }
    }).directive('usersAndAppsNav', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require:'^?usersAndApps',
            replace:true,
            scope:true,
            link:function(scope,elem,attrs,usersAndAppsCtrl){
                scope.toggleView = function(viewName){
                    usersAndAppsCtrl.toggleView(viewName);
                }
            },
            templateUrl:'partials/usersAndApps/throwmeaway'
        }
    });
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="toggleView(FOO_VIEW)">Foo View</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="toggleView(BAR_VIEW)">Bar View</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="toggleView(BAM_VIEW)">Bam View</button>
</div>
```

Directive and nested (child) directive:

```
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <users-and-apps>
        <users-and-apps-nav></users-and-apps-nav>
    </users-and-apps>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine, but since you are not using an isolate or transcluded scope in `usersAndAppsNav`, you don't need to define a controller API on `usersAndApps` — you can simply take advantage of [prototypal scope inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) to access method `toggleViewParent` if you define it on the scope associated with `usersAndApps`:

```
.directive('usersAndApps', function() {
return {
    restrict:'EA',
    scope: true,
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.FOO_VIEW = 'fooView';
        ...
        scope.toggleViewParent = function(viewName){
            console.log('show view ' + viewName);
        }
    }
}
}).directive('usersAndAppsNav', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace:true,
    scope:true,
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs) {
        scope.toggleView = function(viewName){
            scope.toggleViewParent(viewName);
        }
    },
   templateUrl: ...
}
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/8wvkz/).</kbd>

[image]

Note that you are already making use of prototypal inheritance when you write `ng-click="toggleView(FOO_VIEW)"` in your template — the only reason FOO_VIEW evaluates to `fooView` is because of prototypal inheritance — `FOO_VIEW` is defined on the scope associated with `usersAndApps` (scope 004), which the child scope (scope 005) finds via the inheritance chain/lookup (i.e., following the dashed line).

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this quick video tutorial that covers this topic @ http://www.egghead.io/video/LJmZaxuxlRc

He also has a bunch of other really great AngularJS tutorial videos linked off that site.

Comment: Those are great videos, you're right.  I'm looking for something a little more concrete, especially since this particular problem involves manipulating DOM, which should be done at the directive level.

Comment: The video I linked to talks about directives calling controller methods - isn't that what you're asking about? He has another video about directive -> directive communication @ http://www.egghead.io/video/rzMrBIVuxgM

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for.  I'm more interested in a directive talking to a directive's controller (exposed as an API for other directives to talk to it through require:'^?myDirective).  See the code snip above.  Again, thanks for the recommendations.  I'm actually figuring a few things out, and at some point I'll have enough info to answer the question (with the help of egghead videos and the like).  Thanks again!